# Return through all functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

**Is it possible to return through multiple functions?**

I have a jQuery on click function with a $.each loop in it. In the $.each loop I test for various conditions, and if not met display an alert message and then return. Here is a cut down version of my code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.add-to-basket, #add-to-basket', function(e) {
    var data = {
        id: $(this).data('id'),
        quantity: 1
    };
    if($('#quant').length > 0) {
        data.quantity = $('#quant').val();
    }

    var i = 0;
    var j = 0;
    if($('.product-option').length > 0) {
        $('.product-option').each(function(index, element) {
            if($(this).is('select')) {
                //check to see if this is a required select, and return if a selection has not been made.
                if($(this).data("force") == 1 && $(this).val() == 0) {
                    AlertDialogue($(this).data("title") + " requires a selection before you can add this product to your basket.", "Required Option");
                    return;
                }
                data.opts[i++] = $(this).val();
            } else if($(this).is('input[type="checkbox"]:checked')) {
                data.opts[i++] = $(this).val();
            //check to see if this is a required group of checkboxes, and if so at least one has been checked. If not return.
            } else if($(this).is('input[type="checkbox"]')) {
                if($(this).data("force") == 1 && $('input[name="' + $(this).prop("name") + '"]:checked').length == 0) {
                    AlertDialogue($(this).data("title") + " requires at least one option to be checked before you can add this product to your basket.", "Required Option");
                    return;
                }
            } else if($(this).is('input[type="radio"]:checked')) {
                data.opts[i++] = $(this).val();
            } else if($(this).is('textarea')) {
                //Check to see if this is a required textarea, and if so make sure there is some text in it.
                if($(this).data("force") == 1 && $.trim($(this).val()).length == 0) {
                    AlertDialogue($(this).data("title") + " requires text before you can add this product to your basket.", "Required Option");
                    return;
                }
                if($(this).val().length > 0) {
                    data.text[j].id = $(this).data("id");
                    data.text[j++].val = $(this).val();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    //submit product to the cart
});
```

However the return will only break that loop of the $.each loop, and start the next loop. I would like to not only break the $.each loop, but return from the on click function entirely.

1. Is this possible?
2. If so, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

To exit from `$.each` you should `return false`

To exit from event handler function you should use `return`

As per your requirement you can do little like below,

```
var break = false;
$('.product-option').each(function(index, element) {
    // rest of code

    if(condition) {
        break = true;
        return false;           //  this will break out of each loop
    }
});
if(break) {
    return;                    // return from event handler  if break == true;
}
// rest of code
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the docs for [`jQuery.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/):

> We can break the $.each() loop at a particular iteration by making the callback  function return false. Returning non-false is the same
>   as a continue statement in  a for loop; it will skip immediately to
>   the next iteration.

Essentially, use `return false;` instead of just `return;`.

Comment: Thanks for that, that at least gets me half way there. That breaks me out of the $.each permanently, however it doesn't break me out of the original on click function.

Comment: Place a separate return statement then for the the click handler. I can't really give you any code because I don't know what exactly you want to return. If you just want to leave the click handler, place `return false;` before your last bracket. **Note**: This will stop the default event action and event propagation.